# Write pandas dataframe in InfluxDB

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I am writing a python script to save some data in a influxdb.

1. I download some info and create a pandas' table. This is in a for cycle and I mimic it in the sample below exploding two iterations.
2. The downloaded info has in every row a timestamp in Unix Epoch format. I thought it was perfect for the influx, instead it complained: "`Must be DataFrame with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`".
3. I believed that the format of the Timestamp wasn't "influx friendly", so I tried to make it explicity with `df = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')` but I got

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_insert.py", line 24, in <module>
    df = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
  File "/home/mune/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 887, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
  File "/home/mune/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 356, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _to_datetime_with_unit(arg, unit, name, tz, errors)
  File "/home/mune/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 528, in _to_datetime_with_unit
    arr, tz_parsed = tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime(arg, unit, errors=errors)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 324, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1644624000000 with the unit 's'
```

MY SAMPLE CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from influxdb import DataFrameClient

raw_data1 = [['1644624000000', '2.05e-05', '2.067e-05', '1.919e-05', '2.023e-05', '2.183122e+07']]
raw_data2 = [['1644710400000', '2.053e-05', '2.064e-05', '2.053e-05', '2.064e-05', '1.556156e+07']]
header = ['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Exchange', 'Symbol']
header_aux = ['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
indexes = ['Timestamp', 'Exchange', 'Symbol']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)

df_aux1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1,columns=header_aux)
df_aux1['Symbol'] = 'coin_name1'
df_aux1['Exchange'] = 'exch1'
df = df.append(df_aux1)

df_aux2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns=header_aux)
df_aux2['Symbol'] = 'coin_name2'
df_aux2['Exchange'] = 'exch2'
df = df.append(df_aux2)
    
df.set_index(indexes)
print(df)
df = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')

tags = { 'tag2': df['Symbol'] } 
dbClient = DataFrameClient('localhost', 8086, '', '', 'crypto')
dbClient.write_points(df, 'coins', tags = tags)

fromDB = dbClient.query('select * from quotes;')
print(fromDB)
```

These lines are my sample code.
This issue is driving me crazy because I know that I can do with another SQL but I feel that I'm so close to the end that I don't want to give up now.
Thanks in advance for your help.